# How can I install Play Market on an Android Studio Emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-machine

So, I need to create a new virtual device with screen sizes 400x800. I made this, but there is no Play Market in there. How can I install it without creating basic phone where Market is already installed?

Answer (score 0):

Go to AVD manager then Create new Virtual Device then Select the device you want and click next Click on "Recommended" tab and select one of the version with Google Play Written on it and click next then finish

Comment: What if there is no version with Google Play?

Comment: Check the tab "Other Images" and find version with Google Api

Answer (score 0):

You could try following this guide to install/flash open gapps on the virtual device:
https://gist.github.com/cunneen/1c0d9717f8ce5ea76900ba32fa037047#file-readme-md

**It might brick the virtual device though!**

If you just need something to install play store apps and not the whole play services package, then you could also install [Aurora Store](https://auroraoss.com/downloads.php) instead. That can simply be done dragging the apk to the emulator.